# Rails4, How to loop model column name using text array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I looping all weekday data and print on web browser

My DateModel is

```
 monday_start_time: 09:00
           monday_end_time: 
        tuesday_start_time: 
          tuesday_end_time: 
      wednesday_start_time: 
        wednesday_end_time:
       thursday_start_time: 
         thursday_end_time: 
         friday_start_time:
           friday_end_time: 
       saturday_start_time:
         saturday_end_time:
```

And I wanna loop only weekname likes

```
day_data = DayModel.first
days = ["monday", "tuestday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday"]
days.each do |d|
  puts  day_data."d+start_time"
end
```

is it possible loop model column's using text array?

if it possible, how to type on the editor?

Comment: Do you want loop of column names? monday_start_time, Is this your field name?

Comment: @SSR Yes this is field names~